# Change URL from HTML depending of the environment

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Is it possible to change the content of a page depending of the environment I am?

I mean, for example, having two environments:

```
http://www.development-example.com
http://www.production-example.com
```

Is it possible, using the same HTML, to have something like this?

```
<p><a href="http://www.development-example.com OR http://www.production-example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow">Web link</a></p>
```

EDIT: Is it possible to do it through Javascript?

Comment: you can not do it without javascript

Comment: What’s the condition for deciding which URL to use? To use the same domains, use relative paths.

Comment: @RatajS the HTML should be in both URLs, it must detect in which URL it is, so it shows one environment of the other in the link...

Comment: without a backend language, it's not possible !!

Comment: Use relative paths. `<a href="/">bla bla</a>` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the information about the environment somehow. The question is where you want to handle it. You have an option to handle it client-side only, where you'd for example take the URL you are on, figure out which environment it is and then have the elements that are linking somewhere get their `href` attribute programmatically. This is however pretty hackish and if you have a large website content it might even be resource demanding and difficult to maintain if you were to set elements one by one. Normally what you'd do is have placeholders in your website template that would get replaced by data provided by the back-end, which is already *aware* of what environment you are currently on. Something along the lines of

```
<a href="${linkUrl}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow">Web link</a>
```

Where `linkUrl` is provided by the back-end already when the content is being generated.